# html file api accept filter in IE

Tags: html, file, internet-explorer, filter

I'm having problems with IE11 and accept filter for an input file

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" accept=".kml" >
```

The title of the file-browse dialog is "Choose File to Upload". I did set multiple so it should be plural "...File(s)". In fact ideally it should be "..KML file(s)" in the title.

Also the filter is not respected, it is still possible to select all files, gif and html files.

Is there any known workaround for the filter and title issues in IE11 (other than js validation)?

Comment: Are you sure you're not running your app in a legacy document mode? There should be no issues with `accept` attribute in IE11.

Comment: Yeah it has the !doctype html tag, should be html5. It does work fine in Chrome though. I tried in jsfiddle with IE11, it didn't work there either.

Comment: I [can't reproduce your issue](http://jsfiddle.net/myjkfj0s/) with `accept` attribute in IE11. Afaik the title of the dialog can't be changed in any browser. Notice, that a DTD alone doesn't guarantee IE being run in edge mode, maybe there are incorrect options selected in Combatibility View settings?

Comment: Not sure what edge mode is? I'm running default IE settings on an old windows 7 laptop. Our QA dep has said it doesn't work in IE and I can confirm it doesn't work on my IE either. The accept partially "works" in that it shows the ".kml" extension as default, but it does NOT remove the .gif and other extensions which is just as important.

Comment: You can always pick "All files" from the Type of files drop-down in any browser, why to worry about a couple of extra options in IE?

Comment: Because these extra options will only confuse the user. He can't upload image files so it makes no sense he can select them in the dialog. It's like having a button that does nothing on your UI - get rid of it it serves no purpose. Besides it's completely arbitrary to have image files in the list. It might as well be xml files, doc files or something else just a silly.